# How to do multiple arguments with Python Popen?

Tags: python, pygtk, subprocess, popen, gnome-terminal

I am trying to make a PyGtk Gui, that has a button. When the user presses this button, `gnome-terminal` prompts the user to write their password.

Then it will clone this [Git repository](https://github.com/pererinha/gedit-snippet-jquery) for `gedit` JQuery snippets.

And then, it copies the `js.xml` file to `/usr/share/gedit/plugins/snippets/js.xml`

In the end, it forcefully removes the Git repository.

**The command:**

```
gnome-terminal -x sudo git clone git://github.com/pererinha/gedit-snippet-jquery.git && sudo cp -f gedit-snippet-jquery/js.xml /usr/share/gedit/plugins/snippets/js.xml && sudo rm -rf gedit-snippet-jquery
```

It works fine in my terminal.

*But,* via the GUI it just opens, I add my password, press enter, and then it closes again.

I'd like to only run the command to the first `&&`

**This is my Python function (with command):**

```
def on_install_jquery_code_snippet_for_gedit_activate(self, widget):
    """ Install Jquery code snippet for Gedit. """
    cmd="gnome-terminal -x sudo git clone git://github.com/pererinha/gedit-snippet-jquery.git && sudo cp -f gedit-snippet-jquery/js.xml /usr/share/gedit/plugins/snippets/js.xml && sudo rm -rf gedit-snippet-jquery"
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
             close_fds=False)
    self.status.set_text(p.stdout.read()) #show response in 'status
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To directly answer your question, read below. But there's a lot of problems with your program, some of which I cover in "Better practice."

---

By default, [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) commands are supplied as a list of strings.

However, you can also you can use the `shell` argument to execute a command "formatted exactly as it would be when typed at the shell prompt."

**No:**

```
>>> p = Popen("cat -n file1 file2")
```

**Yes:**

```
>>> p = Popen("cat -n file1 file2", shell=True)
>>> p = Popen(["cat", "-n", "file1", "file2"])
```

There are a number of differences between these two options, and valid use cases for each. I won't attempt to summarize the differences- the [`Popen` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) already do an excellent job of that.

---

So, in the case of your commands, you'd do something like this:

```
cmd = "gnome-terminal -x sudo git clone git://github.com/pererinha/gedit-snippet-jquery.git && sudo cp -f gedit-snippet-jquery/js.xml /usr/share/gedit/plugins/snippets/js.xml && sudo rm -rf gedit-snippet-jquery"
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
          close_fds=False)
```

### Better practice

However, using Python as a wrapper for many system commands is not really a good idea. At the very least, you should be breaking up your commands into separate Popens, so that non-zero exits can be handled adequately. In reality, this script seems like it'd be much better suited as a shell script. But if you insist on Python, there are better practices.

The [`os` module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) should take the place of calls to `rm` and `cp`. And while I have no experience with it, you might want to look at tools like [GitPython](http://gitorious.org/git-python) to interact with Git repositories.

#### Compatibility concerns

Lastly, you should be careful about making calls to `gnome-terminal` and `sudo`. Not all GNU/Linux users run Ubuntu, and not everyone has `sudo`, or the GNOME terminal emulator installed. In its current form, your script will crash, rather unhelpfully, if:

- The `sudo` command is not installed
- The user is not in the `sudoers` group
- The user doesn't use GNOME, or its default terminal emulator
- Git is not installed

If you're willing to assume your users are running Ubuntu, calling `x-terminal-emulator` is a much better option than calling `gnome-terminal` directly, as it will call whatever terminal emulator they've installed (e.g. `xfce4-terminal` for users of Xubuntu).

Comment: avoid string splitting, for shell commands there is shlex.split

Comment: To add to above, shlex.split() splits the command preserving quoted arguments as is.

Comment: do not pass a list argument with `shell=True` on POSIX ([the additional list items are passed to `/bin/sh`, not the command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26417712/4279) -- you don't want it in most cases). Use string instead (i.e., drop `shlex.split()` if you use `shell=True`)

Comment: Duly noted, @J.F.Sebastian. I read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) again and revised my answer to match the recommendations there. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: This is... Really unhelpful. Why shouldn't we do any of the examples you listed? You provide no actual reasoning to your statements, so why should I believe anything that you're saying?

Comment: @JamEngulfer - I've now linked to the docs for a thorough explanation of proper syntax of `Popen`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Your **Compatibility concerns** is well-taken but could it perhaps be named **Cross-Platform Developer Concerns vs. Home User non-concerns** or something like that if you get my drift?