# difference between terminal execution and popen

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal, subprocess, popen

Typing the command in my ubuntu terminal recognizes the parameter `t` in my command:

```
/home/daniel/Downloads/SALOME-7.6.0-UB14.04/salome start -t
```

What is the difference when starting the same process in python via Popen?

```
command ='/home/daniel/Downloads/SALOME-7.6.0-UB14.04/salome'
commandargs= 'start -t'

import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([command, commandargs], shell=True).wait()
```

My parameter stands for terminal mode but running my application (salome) via python Popen opens the GUI.

Comment: In `/home/daniel/Downloads/SALOME-7.6.0-UB14.04/salome start -t`, "start" and "-t" are two separate arguments, so they belong as two different list items in the args list (also no point in using `shell=True` in this case)

Comment: use your commandargs like this: `commandargs= ['start',  '-t']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

```
args should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string.
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11309864/2776376

```
subprocess.Popen([command, commandargs.split(' ')], shell=True).wait()
```

alternatively you could do, although less recommended:

```
subprocess.Popen(command + commandargs, shell=True).wait()
```

should do the trick

Comment: `subprocess.Popen((command+' '+ commandargs).split(' '), shell=True).wait()` would be correct, but I have the same problem