# Issues with Python Popen() (Syntax?)

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, os.path

have a small issue with a program I am trying to launch from a Python script via Popen() (I understand Popen() may not be ideal, but I am working with somewhat of a template used in other instances, and want to follow convention).

I am a bit confused, as I can't seem to get the following to run:

```
root = os.getcwd()

bin = 'my_executable.exe'

bin_fullpath = os.path.join(root,bin)

params = 'Option C -f Module -y -q'

p = subprocess.Popen([bin_fullpath,params])

out = p.communicate()
```

The program launches, but exits with error code 1 (I checked with check_call).

However, when I forgo the above method, and simply provide the entire string I need to run, as follows:

```
subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Users\me\Desktop\path\to\tool\my_executable.exe Option C -f Module -y -q')
```

The program executes as expected. Obviously I have something wrong with the sytntax, but I can't figure out what . . .

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do multiple arguments with Python Popen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284147/how-to-do-multiple-arguments-with-python-popen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the "list of arguments" format, each one has to be its own string, as a separate member of the list, like this:

```
params = ['Option', 'C', '-f', 'Module', '-y', '-q']
p = subprocess.Popen([bin_fullpath, *params])
```

---

When you put them all in a single string, you're telling `subprocess` they're all one big argument.<sup>1</sup> So, rather than being the rough equivalent of this command line:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\path\to\tool\my_executable.exe Option C -f Module -y -q
```

… it's the rough equivalent of this one:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\path\to\tool\my_executable.exe "Option C -f Module -y -q"
```

---

If it's not clear why those are different, consider these examples instead:

```
fix.exe "My Pictures\picture1.jpg"
fix.exe My Pictures\picture1.jpg
```

The first one is fixing one picture, `My Pictures\picture1.jpg`. The second is fixing two pictures, `My`, and `Pictures\picture1.jpg`.

---

For more details on the `args` argument, see [Frequently Used Arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments). Notice the "one big string" version is actually not valid without `shell=True`—even though it happens to usually work on Windows.

---

<sub>1. Things are a little more complicated than this on Windows, because `subprocess` actually has to take all of the args and work out how to put them together in a string so that they can be parsed back into the actual separate values the way you asked for them. But never mind that.</sub>

Comment: Awesome, thanks man. Knew it was something trivial like that. This is what late night coding gets you. Tyvm