# How to open a command prompt along with a command to run using a python script?

Tags: python, windows

I tried the below approach to open a command prompt and run a sample command. But it immediately closes:

```
import os
# as of now i am just passing cd /../, later will be changing to a different command
os.system("start /wait cmd /c {cd /../}")
```

I also tried this way, but this opens two command shells:

```
import os
os.system("start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k cd /d D:")
```

[image: Two commands shell are being opened]

Is it possible to just open one command prompt and run the command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import subprocess

cmd = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe /K cd /') 

#subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe /K netstat') # run cmd commands like netstat,..etc
#subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe /K python') # open cmd in  Python live interpreter mode
#subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe /K my_script.py') # run your python script
```

read more https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Comment: also, how do we pass multiple arguments?

Comment: @SuryaTej read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284147/how-to-do-multiple-arguments-with-python-popen)

Answer (score 3):

The CMD window will run the commands you give it and then immediately close on completion, if you want to keep the window open you need to send a pause command:

> os.system("YOUR COMMAND")
>
> os.system("pause")