# Run script for send in-game Terraria server commands

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu

In the past week I install a Terraria 1.3.5.3 server into an Ubuntu v18.04 OS, for playing online with friends. This server should be powered on 24/7, without any GUI, only been accessed by SSH on internal LAN.

My friends ask me if there is a way for them to control the server, e.g. send a message, via internal in-game chat, so I thought use a special character ($) in front of the desired command ('$say something' or '$save', for instance) and a python program, that read the terminal output via pipe, interpreter the command and send it back with a bash command.

I follow these instructions to install the server:

https://www.linode.com/docs/game-servers/host-a-terraria-server-on-your-linode

And config my router to forward a dedicated port to the terraria server.

All is working fine, but I really struggle to make python send a command via "terrariad" bash script, described in the link above.

Here is a code used to send a command, in python:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("terrariad save", shell=True)
```

This works fine, but if I try to input a string with space:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("terrariad \"say something\"", shell=True)
```

it stop the command in the space char, output this on the terminal:

```
: say
```

Instead of the desired:

```
: say something
<Server>something
```

What could I do to solve this problem? 
I tried so much things but I get the same result.

P.S. If I send the command manually in the ssh putty terminal, it works!

Edit 1:

I abandoned the python solution, by now I'll try it with bash instead, seem to be more logic to do this way.

Edit 2:

I found the "terrariad" script expect just one argument, but the Popen is splitting my argument into two no matter the method I use, as my input string has one space char in the middle. Like this:

Expected:

```
terrariad "say\ something"

$1 = "say something"
```

But I get this of python Popen:

```
subprocess.Popen("terrariad \"say something\"", shell=True)

$1 = "say
$2 = something"
```

No matter i try to list it:

```
subprocess.Popen(["terrariad", "say something"])

$1 = "say
$2 = something"
```

Or use \ quote before the space char, It always split variables if it reach a space char.

Edit 3:

Looking in the bash script I could understand what is going on when I send a command... Basically it use the command "stuff", from the screen program, to send characters to the terraria screen session:

```sh
screen -S terraria -X stuff $send
```

$send is a printf command:

```sh
send="`printf \"$*\r\"`"
```

And it seems to me that if I run the bash file from Python, it has a different result than running from the command line. How this is possible? Is this a bug or bad implementation of the function?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do multiple arguments with Python Popen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284147/how-to-do-multiple-arguments-with-python-popen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally come with a solution to this, using pipes instead of the Popen solution.

It seems to me that Popen isn't the best solution to run bash scripts, as described in [How to do multiple arguments with Python Popen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284147/how-to-do-multiple-arguments-with-python-popen), the link that SiHa send in the comments (Thanks!):

"However, using Python as a wrapper for many system commands is not really a good idea. At the very least, you should be breaking up your commands into separate Popens, so that non-zero exits can be handled adequately. In reality, this script seems like it'd be much better suited as a shell script.".

So I came with the solution, using a fifo file:

First, create a fifo to be use as a pipe, in the desired directory (for instance, /samba/terraria/config):

```sh
mkfifo cmdOutput
```

*/samba/terraria - this is the directory I create in order to easily edit the scripts, save and load maps to the server using another computer, that are shared with samba (https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-configure-samba-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Then I create a python script to read from the screen output and then write to a pipe file (I know, probably there is other ways to this):

```py
import shlex, os

outputFile = os.open("/samba/terraria/config/cmdOutput", os.O_WRONLY )


print("python script has started!")
while 1:
    line = input()
    print(line)
    cmdPosition = line.find("&")
    if( cmdPosition != -1 ):
        cmd = slice(cmdPosition+1,len(line))
        cmdText = line[cmd]
        os.write(outputFile, bytes( cmdText + "\r\r", 'utf-8'))
        os.write(outputFile, bytes("say Command executed!!!\r\r", 'utf-8'))
```

Then I edit the terraria.service file to call this script, piped from terrariaServer, and redirect the errors to another file:

```sh
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -dmS terraria /bin/bash -c "/opt/terraria/TerrariaServer.bin.x86_64 -config /samba/terraria/config/serverconfig.txt < /samba/terraria/config/cmdOutput 2>/samba/terraria/config/errorLog.txt | python3 /samba/terraria/scripts/allowCommands.py"
```

*/samba/terraria/scripts/allowCommands.py - where my script is.

**/samba/terraria/config/errorLog.txt - save Log of errors in a file.

Now I can send commands, like 'noon' or 'dawn' so I can change the in-game time, save world and backup it with samba server before boss fights, do another stuff if I have some time XD, and have the terminal showing what is going on with the server.