# execute process with chrt priority

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux

I am wondering if there is any possibility to execute process from python with chrt 1 priority. It makes my timer much more accurate. Here is my piece of code:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["/a.out"])
```

I am doing this task manually by typing in raspberry pi linux terminal: `chrt 1 ./a.out`.
Is there any possibility to run process with chrt attribute via python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do multiple arguments with Python Popen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284147/how-to-do-multiple-arguments-with-python-popen). I mean calling ```p = subprocess.Popen(["chrt", "1", "./a.out"])```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use [sched_setscheduler](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html) in the program directly, eliminating the need for an extra chrt altogether.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny It did. Thanks.