# How to execute a file without the ".exe" extension

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, executable

I have a file: "abc", it's a executable file.
I want to execute it by Phthon or windows CMD.

If I write code:

```
subprocess.Popen('-a -b -c', creationflags=0x08, shell=True, executable="C:\\abc")
```

Then, abc executed, but params(-a -b -c) been ignored

So...How Can I reslove it?

Comment: Have you tried `subprocess.Popen("C://abc -a -b -c", shell=True)`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284147/how-to-do-multiple-arguments-with-python-popen

Comment: this should work. And the preferred way is using an argument list (and drop shell=True). How can you be sure/prove that the arguments are ignored? for instance this works: `p=subprocess.Popen("/c dir",executable=r"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe")`

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your code to the following version

```
args = ['C:\\abc', '-a', '-b', '-c']

p = subprocess.Popen(' '.join(args), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

or without `shell=True` you can further reduce it to

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

or you can use another method to get output from your exe and pass arguments to it

```
Output = subprocess.check_output(' '.join(args), shell=True).decode()
```

Comment: if a executable(c:\\abc) file's name without the ".exe", Popen not work: abc not be called. And when I rename abc to abc.exe, it works

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer myself, which is to use `win32process.CreateProcess`
Thanks to other authors, but their answers are wrong.

The correct answer is:

```
win32process.CreateProcess(r"C:\abc", "-a -b -c", None, None, 0, 0, None, None, win32process.STARTUPINFO())
```

The following answer does not work:

```
subprocess.Popen('-a -b -c', creationflags=0x08, shell=True, executable="C:\\abc")

#or

p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Maybe I really don’t know how to use `subprocess`, but `Windows` is really special. Executable files without a suffix cannot be executed directly on the command line.

Answer (score -1):

In PowerShell

```
& "C:\abc.exe"
```

Comment: This is neither python nor CMD nor a way to call without the `exe` extension.